# Getting error while using fetch api in react app

Tags: reactjs

I have a react app and I want to fetch data from a json file named as data.json which is located in my src folter in the same folder I have my App.js file but the App.js file unable to fetch the data as json

**unable to get the data from the JSON file as json()**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css'

export default function App() {

  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('./data.json')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        setData(data)
      }).catch(error => console.error(error))

  })

  return (
    <>
      <p> {data} </p>
    </>
  );
}
```

When i use get  text response as text() formate I'm getting the index.html's content inside my

tag

```
import './App.css'

export default function App() {



  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('./data.json')
      .then(response => response.text())
      .then(data => {
        setData(data)
      }).catch(error => console.error(error))

  })

  return (
    <>
      <p>use fetch api for fetch data from data.json file <br /> {data} </p>
    </>
  );
}
```

## Can anybody fix my problem, I'm new in stack-overflow

I want to fetch the data from the json file as object or array,
and I'm new here so I don't know more about how to explain so please somebody help me out.

Comment: Have you get check in Network tab of the browser Developer tools what the response of your calling ?

Comment: What 'flavor' of React do you use? Is it Create-React-App, Vite or NextJS?

Comment: @Luty , Yes I have checked my Network tab everything is fine there

Comment: @Aitwar , I use Create-react-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION BASED ON MY TEST**:

Place your `data.json` file inside your `public` folder instead of `src`. It's inaccessible if you will place files in `src`

Code remains same unless you want to change the folder's path.

```js
function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/data.json')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                setData(data)
            }).catch(error => console.error(error))

    })

    return (
        <>
            {JSON.stringify(data)}
        </>
    );
}
```

[image]